# SQL Query Table doesn't exsist

Tags: mysql, sequelpro

When I am writing a query via Sequel Pro and format it like this `a.TBL_ADJUSTMENT` I get the following error `Table 'a.TBL_ADJUSTMENT' doesn't exist`.

How can I write it so that I can label my tables with a letter/number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to select the column `my_column` from the table `my_table`, the query you are looking for is `select a.my_column from my_table as a`

[Aliases](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to a Table Schema:

```
select a.Table_name from
(select * from information_schema.`TABLES` a) as a
```

Comment: You can add where condition if you want to specify your table name.